# Force to start XBMC in fullscreen mode?

Tags: 13.04, gnome, fullscreen, xbmc

I really tried:

```
xbmc -fs
```

And using the script way:

```
xbmc
sleep 10
wmctrl -x -r XBMC Media Center.XBMC Media Center -b toggle,fullscreen
```

From [this](http://www.rizsilverthorn.net/linux/xbmc-on-dual-monitors/) script.

And yes, I know the key "|\" exists to switch between windowed and fullscreen. **But I want to force to always in fullscreen mode**.

None this works. Any sugestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way to **really force** the XBMC to start in *fullscreen mode*, just editing the xml config file [advancedsettings.xml](http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=advancedsettings.xml):

```
nano ~/.xbmc/userdata/advancedsettings.xml
```

And puting the content:

```
<advancedsettings>
  <fullscreen>true</fullscreen>
</advancedsettings>
```

Or simply do this using this command:

```
echo "<advancedsettings><fullscreen>true</fullscreen></advancedsettings>" > ~/.xbmc/userdata/advancedsettings.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Fullscreen is the default. Go into the System → Video settings and make sure you're not using a windowed mode.

Answer (score 0):

I switch window/full for different situations.  But I have one particular case I need to to force windowed (you could force full with same approach).  So here's how I do that at startup time (in a wrapper script).

```
ORIG_FILE=/home/me/.xbmc/userdata/guisettings.xml
BACK_FILE=${ORIG_FILE}.backup
cp $ORIG_FILE $BACK_FILE
awk '{if (index($0,"screenmode") > 0){ print "<screenmode>WINDOW</screenmode>" } else {print $0}}' $BACK_FILE > $ORIG_FILE
```